# remove skype birthdays from outlook.com calendar

Tags: skype, calendar, outlook.com

I'm using Outlook.com (live.com) for my e-mail, contacts and calendar. Since Skype was merged into outlook somehow my calendar shows the birthdays of my skype contacts, but I don't want them in my birthday calendar.

I tried removing the birthday calendar and adding it again, to the effect of my outlook contacts have vanished from the birthday calendar. So now it does show *only* the skype birthdays, which is the exact opposite of what I wanted to achieve.

My question: How do I remove the skype contacts birthday from my outlook.com birthday calendar and how do I add my outlook.com contacts birthdays to my birthday calendar again, so I only see the birthdays of my Outlook.com contacts and none else?

Comment: I also would like to know this

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do it?